# How to loop through sql sum results in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, foreach

I need to sum up the result of the total column:

```
SELECT SUM(number_guest) AS total, booking_time
   FROM mt_bookingtable
   WHERE
            merchant_id IN (SELECT merchant_id 
                              FROM mt_merchant 
                              WHERE merchant_id = 1 )
            AND booking_time BETWEEN "12:00" AND "20:00"
            AND
            date_booking like "2020-06-01"
            AND status in ('pending','approved')
   GROUP BY booking_time
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju2jd.png)

I tried to use foreach like this:

```
foreach ($res as $item) {
    $sum += $item['total'];
    return $sum;
}
```

But I got the result `null`.

Comment: `return $sum;` in your loop will stop at the first iteration.

Comment: You got the value from sql query ? If Y then try to declare value $sum = 0 before loop and sum the total values and return $sum after complete the loop.like
$sum = 0;
foreach ($res as $item ) {
    $sum += $item['total'];
}
    return $sum;

Comment: its still send me the first iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT SUM(number_guest) AS total
FROM mt_bookingtable
WHERE merchant_id IN (SELECT merchant_id FROM mt_merchant WHERE merchant_id = 1 ) AND
      booking_time BETWEEN '12:00' AND '20:00' AND
      date_booking like '2020-06-01' AND
      status in ('pending', 'approved');
```

Comment: I get that, but what if i need to show the booking time on a different page, should i do a second query just for the booking_time? when i can get it in this query already?

Comment: @G.Obeng . . . That is really not clear from your question.  I would suggest that you ask a new question with appropriate sample data and desired results.